# Disable checkout after "add to source" in clearcase

Tags: view, element, clearcase, vcs-checkout, vob

I need to add a source to an element so that operations like modified or checkout the file is prevented after the element is added. Is that possible? How should the permissions be set to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

On that file, you try and lock it (if you are the owner):

```
 cleartool lock yourFile@@
```

(note the @@ to impact the element, not the version)

See [`cleartool lock`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm).

That works if you are the owner of that object (if you added it yourself).

So it isn't so much a "permission" issue (as in `chmod`); rather a lock issue.
See more at the section "**Locks on VOB objects**" of the article "[VOB and view access control](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/access-control.htm)".

Comment: @user3257666 yes: if you lock a folder, you don't prevent checkout on the *existing* elements, but you are preventing any removal or "add to source control" within that folder.

Comment: The problem is that I locked the folder I cannot upload more elements and i dont want that. I want to be able to add more elements in that folder but prevent checkout or modification on the elements that are already in that folder

Comment: @user3257666 simply unlock the folder (in order for you to upload new elements). Then put a lock on any file within that folder.